# Node User model getting TypeError: Cannot set property 'getUserId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a User model, but I am getting:

> 2018-12-18 09:47:07.567 [error]: uncaughtException: Cannot set
>   property 'getUserId' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property
>   'getUserId' of undefined

Here's the model:

```
var User = (userId, name, lastname) => {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.tokenizeSingle = null;
    this.tokenizeFile = null;
    this.detokenizeSingle = null;
    this.detokenizeFile = null;
}

User.prototype.getUserId = () => {
    return this.userId;
}

User.prototype.getName = () => {
    return this.name;
}

User.prototype.getLastname = () => {
    return this.name;
}

User.prototype.getFullName = () => {
    return this.name + ' ' + this.lastname;
}

User.prototype.getTokenizeSingle = () => {
    return this.tokenizeSingle;
}

User.prototype.getTokenizeFile = () => {
    return this.tokenizeFile;
}

User.prototype.getDetokenizeSingle = () => {
    return this.detokenizeSingle;
}

User.prototype.getDetokenizeFile = () => {
    return this.detokenizeFile;
}

User.prototype.setPermissions = (tokenizeSingle, tokenizeFile, detokenizeSingle, detokenizeFile) => {
    this.tokenizeSingle = tokenizeSingle || null;
    this.tokenizeFile = tokenizeFile || null;
    this.detokenizeSingle = detokenizeSingle || null;
    this.detokenizeFile = detokenizeFile || null;
}

module.exports = User;
```

I am also using VS Code and it is not suggesting anything when I do: `var newUser = new User(1, 'Rand', 'Fisk');` putting a dot in `newUser` doesn't show any of the options set in the prototype.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions doesn't have its own `this`-context. Change to regular functions and it should work:

```
function User(userId, name, lastname) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.name = name;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.tokenizeSingle = null;
    this.tokenizeFile = null;
    this.detokenizeSingle = null;
    this.detokenizeFile = null;
}

User.prototype.getUserId = function() {
    return this.userId;
}
```

Comment: Should all the prototype setting also be changed to regular functions?

Comment: Yes. If you don't, `this` will be equal to `this` from outer scope, e.g. `window`. That's how arrow functions work.

Comment: @FedeE. Glad I could help :)